# Kubernetes Ingress issue baremetal

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes, installed 3 nodes k8s cluster through kubeadm in my personal Laptop on top of VMware Workstation
a master and 2 worker nodes.

I have deployed nginx ingress controller through below URL, seems nginx ingress pods are working fine, I have deployed a httpd pod, service and ingress to point to the http server, but I am not able to point to the http URL, pasted all files.

**But I didn't deploy any LoadBalancers(HAproxy/MetalLB), I am in a dilemma whether LoadBalancer or  Proxy required  to make ingress working on BareMetal multinode cluster.**

```
# nginx-ingress
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

```
[root@kube-master01 ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                      STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
kube-master01             Ready    master   197d   v1.19.0
kube-node01.example.com   Ready    worker   197d   v1.19.0
kube-node02.example.com   Ready    worker   197d   v1.19.0
```

```
[root@kube-master01 ~]# kubectl -n ingress-nginx get pods
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-5zcd5        0/1     Completed   0          41h
ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-pt5nl   1/1     Running     0          3h4m
```

```
[root@minikube01 httpd]# cat httpd-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
  labels:
    app: http-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: http-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: http-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: http-server
        image: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```
[root@minikube01 httpd]# cat httpd-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: http-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 80
```

```
[root@minikube01 httpd]# cat httpd-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: httpd-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: httpd.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: httpd-service
          servicePort: 8081
```

```
The same above files works fine in a minikube node without any issues.
```

Any assiatnace is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance
Niru

Comment: you have deployed the ingress controller checked got any LB ip as you have to map that IP to DNS or local host /etc/hosts file

Comment: ```[root@kube-master01 ~]# kubectl get ing
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   hello-world.info   192.168.9.56   80      103m
[root@kube-master01 ~]#
```

Comment: The below link has clues, why we need ingress and MetalLB
`https://superuser.com/questions/1522616/metallb-vs-nginx-ingress-in-kubernetes#:~:text=Metallb%20is%20a%20load%20balancer,provides%20routing%20to%20different%20routes.`

Comment: so if you are running minikube on baremetal metalLB required. thanks for updating

Comment: MetalLB is working fine, This thread can be closed

Comment: you can update the answer and mark it as answer and close it.